# Android KeyEvent Not registering

Tags: android, android-edittext, keylistener, keyevent

i am trying to listen for certain key events in android , i attached the event listener to a an Edit Text. i am looking for the space-bar press,pound and @ key.for some reason this event gets only fired for the space bar and the number keys. The function doesn't even gets to be executed for any other key.... i would like to know why ? is their something that i am doing wrong ?

```
package com.stv.mynotes;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class TestActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnKeyListener
{

    EditText edit_txt;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);
        edit_txt = (EditText) (findViewById(R.id.test_txt));
        edit_txt.setOnKeyListener(this);
    }
    public boolean onKey(View v,int keyCode,KeyEvent event)
    {
        int tmpCode = event.getKeyCode();
        if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
        {
            if (tmpCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SPACE)
            {
                Log.i("Test", "Space pressed:"+tmpCode);
                return true;
            }
            if (tmpCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_9)
            {
                Log.i("Test", "9 pressed:"+tmpCode);
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                Log.i("Test","Unknown Down:"+tmpCode);
                return false;
            }
        }
        if(event.getAction()==KeyEvent.ACTION_UP)
        {
            if (tmpCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POUND)
            {
                Log.i("Test", "Pound pressed:"+tmpCode);
                return true;
            }
            if (tmpCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_AT)
            {
                Log.i("Test", "@ pressed:"+tmpCode);
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                Log.i("Test","Unknown UP:"+tmpCode);
                return false;
            }
        }
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this here  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/method/KeyListener.html about onClickListener:

> Key presses on soft input methods are not required to trigger the methods in this listener, and are in fact discouraged to do so.The default android keyboard will not trigger these for any key to any application targetting Jelly Bean or later, and will only deliver it for some key presses to applications targetting Ice Cream Sandwich or earlier.

Also:

> Note that for most cases this interface has been superceded by general soft input methods as defined by InputMethod; it should only be used for cases where an application has its own on-screen keypad and also wants to process hard keyboard events to match it.

So, if you are in the situation described above, try to reconsider you code as recommended by documentation.
As an alternative, you could try to use this:

```
 edit_txt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        int initialLength = 0;
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            initialLength = edit_txt.getText().length();
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            int newLength = edit_txt.getText().length();
            if(newLength<initialLength) return;
            if(edit_txt.getText().charAt(newLength-1)=='@'){
                Log.i("test", "@");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
    });
```

Comment: That is True , KeyEvents are only for physical keys , such as volume and power button , your suggestion is correct. Listening to input events only with key inputs is deprecated , input now can be from a microphone ...i was abel to implement it using text watcher .

Thanks.